Adding a seconf PV inverter
I had a single string of 8 PV connected to an inverter which then connects to a grid generation meter.
Due to some building work I have had to reconfigure the system - which now consists of a string of 6 PV and a second string of 2 PV mounted at a different orientation. I have purchased a 2nd inverter for the new second string. My question is how can I add the AC output of the new inverter such that it is recorded by my generation meter.
Currently there is an isolator switch between the main inverter and the meter - can I wire the output of the 2nd inverter to this switch or will it all go bang.
Main inverter is a SunnyBoy 1700 by SMC:
https://www.eco-logisch.nl/pdfupload/SMA%20SB%201700.pdf
the 2nd new inverter is an Ecoflow MicroInveter:
https://eu.ecoflow.com/products/powerstream-microinverter
I'm proceeding with extreme caution hence the question.

If they are modelled as PFC current sources, OK if modelled as voltage sources, bang.

@greybeard post updated with the inverter models
